# Word for the separation of two parties in writing?

Tags: word-choice, books

In *The Screwtape Letters*, Screwtape divides the demons from the angels in his arguments. He describes them and then describes "our" ideals. What is the name for this? To split two groups apart and to create an enemy?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange ELU! Can you please post more of a context for this description? Along with the context from the Letters, can you include a link to the source. Also, include your opinion on it. What do you think and what research have you done?

Comment: Absent context, "alienation" or "meiosis”?

Comment: Could you please post a sentence or paragraph?

Answer (score 2):

***polarize***

> [polarize
>   Thesaurus.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/polarize)
>   verb (used with object), polarized, polarizing.
>
> 1.
>   to cause polarization in.
>
> 2.
>   **to divide into sharply opposing factions, political groups, etc.:**
>
> *The controversy has polarized voters into proabortion and antiabortion groups.*
>
> 3.
>   to give polarity to.
>   verb (used without object), polarized, polarizing.
>
> 4.
>   to become polarized.